# Azure Blob setcontainer ACL using PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to update container ACL using latest Azure-PHP sdk.

```
setContainerAcl($container, $acl, $options = null)
```

In $container i gave my container name, but in $acl i don't know what to provide?
But I can able to GET the container acl data using getContainerAcl method.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code here for `setContainerAcl`: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/BlobRestProxy.php#L946, `$acl` should be an object of type `ContainerAcl` which you will need to request first using the container name.  The source code for `ContainerACL` can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Blob/Models/ContainerACL.php.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what should be requested first using container name. It would be great if you provide an PHP based example.